# Milliseconds in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

like current time/date, is it possible to get the current milliseconds in 6 digits?

I am using datetime and date to get the timestamp n date

```
call symput('currdatets',datetime());
call symput('currdate',date());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data _null_;
    call symput('nowAsDateTime',put(datetime(), datetime26.6));
    call symput('nowMs',1E6 * datetime()); * but this might generate overflow *;
    call symput('nowMsOnly',1E6 * mod(datetime(), 1));
run;
%put  _USER_;
```

Comment: May i know how to get the millisecond in a variable?

Comment: I am getting the timestamp as "28APR2022:21:27:35.208222"

X= put(datetime(), datetime26.6);

instead i need only millisecond (208222).

Comment: You might have been clear from the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
data _null_;
  dt = datetime() ;
  ms = mod(dt,1) ; /* remainder when divided by 1 */
  put dt= ms= ;
run ;
```